# Is using keepSynced() on Query instead of on DatabaseRef make any difference?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently getting a single dataSnapshot from Firebase like so:

```
public Task<DataSnapshot> getLatestMessage(@NonNull String roomId) {
    final TaskCompletionSource<DataSnapshot> source = new TaskCompletionSource<>();
    DatabaseReference dbRef = mDatabase.getReference(NODE_MESSAGES).child(roomId);
    dbRef.keepSynced(true);
    ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            source.setResult(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            source.setException(databaseError.toException());
        }
    };
    Query query = dbRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
    return source.getTask();
}
```

Notice that I called `keepSynced()` on `dbRef` object already.

Here's the sample data structure:

```
/root
  /messages
    /$roomId
      /$messageId
        /content
        /timestamp
        /etc...
```

I am able to get the most recent single snapshot data as expected, but I was wondering, does it make any difference if I move the `keepSynced()` call in the `Query` object instead of the `DatabaseReference`? i.e.

```
    // dbRef.keepSynced(true); >> REMOVE THIS <<
    ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {...};
    Query query = dbRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
    query.keepSynced(true); // >> ADD THIS <<
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
```

We're currently averaging 50% load (per day) on Firebase right now and with the steady inflow of users, I was wondering if it could improve anything in the app somehow, specially with the load. I even tried something as silly as this:

```
    dbRef.keepSynced(true);
    ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {...};
    Query query = dbRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
    dbRef.keepSynced(false);
```

-- enabling `keepSynced()` at the start to make sure that the reference is pointing to the most recent version, then disabling it after querying and adding the listener. Unfortunately, this doesn't provide the fresh data, not like when keeping it enabled.

I've already gone through the [Optimization DB Performance documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/optimize) and believe that I followed the suggested practices as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the `keepSynced()` call on a `limitToLast()` query will not make any difference on the load on the database server. The server needs to load the exact same data and monitor it, it just only returns the last item to the client.

I recommend using `keepSynced` sparingly in your app. Each call to `keepSynced` keeps an empty listener to the reference/query you attach it to. That means that each client has an active listener to each chat room you call `keepSynced` on, even when the user is not looking at that room. While that may be precisely the right call for the use-cases of your app, it will limit the scalability of your app.

If you're worried about reaching peak load, you might want to consider looking into how to [shard your data over multiple databases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding). Chat apps are typically relatively easy to shard, since each chat room is already isolated.